# C# Add WS-Security SOAP Header Using X509

Tags: c#, .net, security, soap, x509certificate

I'm trying to add a WS-Security header to my SOAP request in C#. The WS-Security header must contain a timestamp element (including elements for "created" and "expires") and a binary security token element. Finally, there need to be a signature. This has to be done using an X509 certificate.

I know how to make an XML signature using SignedXml, but I don't know how to make the WS-Security elements. I have been searching a lot on the internet, but I can't really find any examples including the timestamp element and the binary security token using an X509 certificate. All the examples I can find includes a username and a password and that is not what I'm looking for.

Do I have to make the WS-Security header manually? I feel like there must be a more convenient solution to this in C#.

Comment: It is XML and you can add elements to the XML easily.  So you can start with an existing Header and modify as necessary.  Not all headers are exactly the same so you usually have to customize the standard library methods.

Comment: But aren't there any standard methods for WS-Security headers in C#? For example, SignedXml can generate the necessary XML tags for signing. Are there really no methods to generate some of the XML tags for WS-Security?

Comment: Signing is just the nodes for containing the signing, not what is in the header and body.